# Images failing to upload

Tags: product, product-images, image-upload

When I try to upload an image to a product in the back end, the upload 'bar' turns red and nothing happens. Is there any obvious reason why this might be happening?

Before pressing Upload files:

[image: backend]

After:

[image: back-end]

Comment: Did you search this site already? Did you check the logs?

Comment: Upgrade adobe flash player

Comment: @mam08ixo I had a search of the site and couldn't find a solution. Is there a post I should look at?

Comment: @zhartaunik There isn't anything wrong with the flash player as I'm able to upload images to another instance of magento on another site

Answer (score 1):

Please set the `permission of 777 to the media folder` AND renaming the `.htaccess` to `.htaccessbkp` 
logged out, cleared the cache, logged back in and checked!!